# Angular 6 Subject Subscribe is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, reactivex

I have an [http interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) which  emits a 'string' whenever a request starts and end:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingIndicatorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  private loadingIndicatorSource = new  Subject<string>();
  private loadingIndicator$ = this.loadingIndicatorSource.asObservable();

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.updateVisibility('block');
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
        finalize(
          () => {
            this.updateVisibility('none');
          }
        )
      )
      ;
  }

  updateVisibility(state: string) {
    this.loadingIndicatorSource.next(state);
  }

  getLoadingIndicator() {
    return this.loadingIndicator$;
  }
}
```

This is the component where I injected the service:

```
export class AppComponent {


  display = 'none';

  constructor(public  authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
              public loadingIndicatorService: LoadingIndicatorService) {
    this.loadingIndicatorService.getLoadingIndicator().subscribe(visibility => {
      console.log(visibility);
      this.display = visibility;
    });

    }
  }
```

Actually I am trying to show a loading indicator:

```
 <div [style.display]="display">
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" color="warn" ></mat-progress-bar>
  </div>
```

I flowed [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) tutorial from the official Angular site.

But the subscribe method never executes.

Why subscribe method is not working?

Comment: Browser says : "TypeError: this.loadingIndicator$.next is not a function".
Here is my imports : `import {Observable, Subject} from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Your code is `this.loadingIndicatorSource.next(state)` but your error is `this.loadingIndicator$.next`. Please post the code in error.

Comment: Sorry there was another comment but it deleted and my comment remain from it.
Somebody said use '`this.loadingIndicator$.next(state)`" and after that he deleted comment.

Comment: I would store `this.loadingIndicatorService.getLoadingIndicator()` in a variable and subscribe to that variable. Will look a whole lot better.

Comment: It isn't triggered because interceptors need an HTTP request to be used. Since you don't make one, the `next` method is never called, meaning you don't run the subscription.

Comment: I did http request. I debugged and use the console.log when I did a request, interceptor is working and `next` methods running but `subscribe` method is not working.

Comment: Use `BehaviorSubject` instead `Subject`, I think it cause life cycle

Comment: @theblindprophet yes now it look beter but not working.  `next` functions are calling but they don't triger `subscribe ` function.

Comment: Make a [mcve] to reproduce the issue, because every response you give to solutions is "subscribe isn't called".

Comment: @JimmyHo I tried `new BehaviorSubject('none');` instead of `new  Subject<string>()` but did not work. Could you suggest some example for this situation like creating custom observable in a service and listening it from in a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i would do is create a SpinnerService and a SpinnerInterceptor and not merge them together.

Make the spinner service allocate the amount of outstanding requests and show the spinner if the outstanding requests are greater than 0.

```
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
    private requestAmount$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

public showSpinner$ = this.requestAmount$.asObservable().pipe(map(r => r > 0));

requestStart() {
    this.requestAmount$.next(this.requestAmount$.getValue() + 1);
}

requestEnd() {
    this.requestAmount$.next(this.requestAmount$.getValue() - 1);
}
}
```

Inside your spinnerInterceptor you can inject the SpinnerService and update it based on each request.

```
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        this.spinnerService.requestStart();

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                this.spinnerService.requestEnd();
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Inside your app component use the `ngOnInit` hook do not use the constructor it is against the style guide.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{


  display = 'none';

  constructor(public  authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
              public spinnerService: SpinnerService) {}
ngOnInit(){
    this.spinnerService.showSpinner$.subscribe(visibility => {
      console.log(visibility);
      this.display = visibility ? 'block': 'none';
    });

    }
  }
```

Separation makes it easier to read and understand.

Hope this helped!